# Including System.Data.Entity in POCO library for UserIdentity?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I have separated all my POCO objects into a separate class library, which has no dependencies, they are all just basic objects, as recommended.

My DbContext is in a separate class Library, which references EntityFramework.

Now i need to add users to my DbContext, so i need to change my DbContext to inherit from IdentityDbContext, which also requires that you supply an object to use as the User (which must inherit from UserIdentity).

Now to keep all my entities separated, i would put this "ApplicationUser" class in my POCO class library, but since i need to reference IdentityUser, i am going to have to reference EntityFramework.

Is there any other way to go about it, or is keeping the POCO library separate from my DbContext completely pointless?

Comment: In my personal experience I have named my Project like this "project.Data" I use that to contain all POCO's and EF Context. Instead of thinking of it as a POCO project think of it as your Database Project - It is everything you need to communicate with your DB. If you use EF, then it needs to include those references. I also put my repositories in that same project separated by folder structure.

Comment: You should be able to keep ApplicationUser in the library with EF, instead of adding it to your POCO library, and still add a `DbSet<ApplicationUser>` . Presumably you're separating it to allow business logic, etc. to access your POCOs without extra dependencies, this should do the trick.